# Requiring a GitHub project in SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, svn

I'm helping develop a software product using Java (Eclipse Kepler for RCP Developers is our IDE) that is made up of dozens of plug-ins. We store all of these in an SVN repo on Sourceforge.

We have just been told that due to a legal problem, one of the plugins cannot be accessed via a SVN repo.

I moved it to GitHub and then imported it into my workspace, but am now unable to get the project to build in Maven. I receive this error:

```
Child module /x/x/x/github.project of /x/x/x/project.build/pom.xml does not exist.
```

The pom.xml file of project.build contains this line

```
        <module>../../github.project</module>
```

Which should still be correct.

The pom.xml of the plugin project has not been modified, so it still shares the same group ID as the other plugin and all of the parent information is correct.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to properly integrate this plug-in? Is there a way to "require" a GitHub project in SVN or a different way to ensure it's included?

Thanks.

Comment: Um...what the hell sort of legal problem comes from using a particular version control system?!

Comment: That code was authored by a collaborator who is employed by a different organization. Don't ask me why, because I don't understand it either, but we have to move the code to be permitted to use it.